# Jquery + Ajax is not working properly, why?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, counter

This code will show a counter when there's rows with the status = `unread`, and it will `UPDATE` the row to status = `read` when the user click on the a icon `<i class="fas fa-bell"></i>`.

The problem is: This is not working propelly, when i click on the `<i class="fas fa-bell"></i>` it get a delay of 3-9 seconds to update the counter to 0, it update my table instantly, only the counter that get some delay, but sometimes i need to reload the page and click on the icon to update my table, why? What's wrong?

html:
`<span class="text-white divCountNT" id="datacount"></span>`

script:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#datacount").load("select.php");

    setInterval(function(){
    $("#datacount").load('select.php')
    }, 10000);

  });

  $(document).on('click', '.fa-bell', function (){

    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "update.php"
    });

  });
</script>
```

select.php:

```
<?php
require_once 'db.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION))session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
  $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
}

$status = 'unread';
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM noti WHERE status = :status AND user_id = :user_id");
$sql->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sql->bindParam(':status', $status, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->execute();
$countNT = $sql->rowCount();

if($countNT >= 1){
echo $countNT;
}

?>
```

update.php:

```
<?php
require_once 'db.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION))session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
  $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
}

$status = 'read';
$sql = $conn->prepare("UPDATE noti SET status = :status WHERE user_id = :user_id");
$sql->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sql->bindParam(':status', $status, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->execute();
$countNT = $sql->rowCount();

echo $countNT;

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont have a callback function for your ajax call so your table only updates itself with load function. Your ajax call should be something like that :

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "update.php"
}).done(function() {
   window.location.reload(true);
});
```

Comment: I added this line, now i solved the problem with the delay, but i still need to refresh the page to be able to update my table

Comment: Refresh the page? How do you populate table data? With inline php code or ajax? If inline then you must refresh the page but if ajax then you can just recall that ajax call.

Comment: I did not understand you questions, i only used Ajax on this script in my question.

Comment: Alright. I updated the answer. I guess you want the page to be reloaded after update. Right?

Comment: I realized why i need to reload the page, because of this line `if($countNT >= 1){
echo $countNT;
}`, now it's working fine

Answer (score 0):

You can Try with this code It's Working Fine

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "update.php"
   success: function(result){
        $(body).find("#loadData").html(result);
       // $(body).find("#loadData").append(result); //you can also use for append data insted of replace
   }
   error: function(xhr){
        alert("An error occured: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
   }
});
```

check this  for use of more methods of AJAX https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp